# SSRS Email Sending As .MSG Attachment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I recently migrated our SQL Reporting Services from 2008 to 2012.

We have a number of subscriptions setup that go to managers and most of them like to receive the report as an Excel Spreadsheet.

These seem to get delivered as an email, that is then attached to another email so the manager received an email with a .msg they then have to open, to then open the excel spreadsheet.

Is there anyway to change this behaviour so it is just the email with the excel spreadsheet on it.

Comment: How are you generating the first `.msg`? Using a custom extension? The delivery format you described is not built-in in SSRS.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I'm not using a custom extension that is EXACTLY how it is coming out from SSRS.

Comment: If you are sending email to a phone check [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1164233) related bug reported. Also check [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1164233) thread where they discuss about a similar issue after a migration. I'd check the configuration of the smtp server too.